# Realizar SELECT con slash en sqlite

Tags: android-studio, sqlite, select, android-sqlite

Necesito hacer una busqueda de una pk la cual consta de 8 numeros un slash(/) y otro numero(11222333/4)
pero no me realiza la busqueda, pero si le saco el / me funciona el select, la cosa es que lo necesito con el / aqui va el codigo:

```
View vista;
Button btnBuscar;
EditText txtRut;
TextView txtHoraIngreso, txtNumeroEntregado, txtMarca, txtColor;
AdminSqlOpenHelper conn;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    vista=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slideshow, container, false);

    conn=new AdminSqlOpenHelper(getContext(),"bbdd",null,1);

    btnBuscar=(Button)vista.findViewById(R.id.btnBuscar);

    txtRut=(EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtRut3);
    txtHoraIngreso=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txtHoraIngreso3);
    txtNumeroEntregado=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txtNumeroEntregado3);
    txtMarca=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txtMarca3);
    txtColor=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txtColor3);

    btnBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buscar();
        }
    });

    return vista;
}

private void buscar(){
    SQLiteDatabase ldb=conn.getReadableDatabase();
    String rut=txtRut.getText().toString();
    try {
        Cursor cursor=ldb.rawQuery("select id_estacionamiento, hora_ingreso, marca_bicicleta, color_bicicleta from lugar_ocupado where rut_alumno="+rut,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            txtNumeroEntregado.setText(cursor.getString(0));
            txtHoraIngreso.setText(cursor.getString(1));
            txtMarca.setText(cursor.getString(2));
            txtColor.setText(cursor.getString(3));
            cursor.close();
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Creo que necesito una validacion pero no se me ocurre como hacerla

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el único problema es que debes definir la consulta definiendo el campo como una cadena de caracteres, definiendo como contenedores las comillas sencillas (`'` y `'`), de esta forma tu consulta funcionaría sin problema:

```
Cursor cursor=ldb.rawQuery("select id_estacionamiento, hora_ingreso, marca_bicicleta, color_bicicleta from lugar_ocupado where rut_alumno='"+rut+"'",null);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, ahí me funciono de maravilla!!!